# Como Usar DisplayText/DisplayFormat TStringField clientdatset Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Olá quero formatar os campos da minha tabela que são senha, quero que exiba **** ao inves da senha.

tentei usar o metodo pareceido para formatar valores

```
TFloatField(dm1.q.fieldbyname('preco_prod')).DisplayFormat := 'R$ 0.00';
```

Só que em TStringField não tem o format tem DisplayText e outros mas nenhum funcionou.

Alguém pode me dizer como usar uma formatação para texto corretamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma simples de se conseguir realizar isto é utilizando evento `onGetText` do `TField`

A assinatura do método é

```
procedure(Sender: TField; var Text: String; DisplayText: Boolean)
```

daí você pode criar um método

```
procedure onGetTextPasswordField(Sender: TField; var Text: String; DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
  if Displaytext then
    Text := '**********'
  else
    Text := Sender.AsString;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá, você tem que definir esta máscara no componente visual a ser utilizado para exibir o campo, por exemplo a propriedade "PasswordChar" de um TDBEdit / TEdit, por padrão o valor default do campo é "#0", você deve muda-lo para "*" ou qualquer outro caractere que deseja utilizar como máscara.

---

Editado:

Você vai precisar herdar a classe do TString List na sua própria classe:

```
  TMyGrid = class(TStringGrid)
  protected
     function CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit; override;
     procedure DrawCell(ACol, ARow: Longint; ARect: TRect; AState: TGridDrawState); override;
  end;
```

E em seguida implementar os métodos redeclarados:

```
function TMyGrid.CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit;
begin
   Result := TInplaceEdit.Create(Self);
   if (Passwd) then
      TMaskEdit(Result).PasswordChar := '*';
end;

procedure TMyGrid.DrawCell(ACol, ARow: Integer; ARect: TRect;
  AState: TGridDrawState);
begin
   if (Passwd) then
      Canvas.TextRect(ARect, ARect.Left+2, ARect.Top+2, StringOfChar('*', Length(Cells[ACol, ARow])))
   else
      Canvas.TextRect(ARect, ARect.Left+2, ARect.Top+2, Cells[ACol, ARow]);
end;
```

e então você pode usar o seu TStringGrid customizado:

```
   meuGrid := TMyGrid.Create(Self);
   meuGrid.Parent := Self;
   meuGrid.Left := 5;
   meuGrid.Top := 5;
   meuGrid.Width := 400;
   meuGrid.Height := 400;
   meuGrid.Options := meuGrid.Options + [goEditing];
```

Aí vai funcionar, vc só precisa definir a lógica da variável "Passwd"

Abraços.

Comment: isto no componente, mas estou querendo formatar em uma stringgrid

Comment: É um pouco complicado, mas editei a resposta, dá uma olhada lá...